# How does browser determine whether to download or show

Tags: browser, http-headers

I have a web resource which returns json content with `Content-Type:application/json`. Usually the content is displayed in browser directly but sometimes it's not, instead, a download prompt shows.

I know there's a header `Content-Disposition:inline/attachment` which can explictly tell browser whether to download or show. But if I don't specify this header, how does browser decide? What's its strategy?

Answer (score 4):

From Mozilla's [File types and download actions](http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions) (emphasis mine):

> When you click a link to download a file, **the MIME type determines what action is taken**. If you see an "Opening " dialog asking if you want to save the file or open it with a specified application, that normally means that your Mozilla application **cannot handle the MIME type internally, no plugin is installed and enabled that can handle it and you have not previously selected a download action or helper application to always use for that type of file**.

The browser comes preconfigured to handle basic formats like images. Plugins (which may be bundled with the browser) add handling for various common file types like pdfs. There can also be "helper applications", which means the browser downloads and forwards the file automatically to the application (such as a torrent magnet link opening your torrent client)

Everything else, it will ask until a user binds a default action (if the `Content-Type` is `application/octet-stream`, you can't set a default action). The other browsers work the same.

Answer (score 1):

What `Content-Type` is specified in the header? If the browser doesn't know what it is, it probably defaults to `application/octet-stream` and prompts for download.

[Here's a brief blog about it.](http://mattryall.net/blog/2008/03/default-content-type)