# API return data in CSV format

Tags: csv, express

I'm creating an API which should return data in a CSV format. I set the content-type header to text/csv but this forces a download of the contents as a csv file.

I'm using NodeJS and the express framework. It could be that this is standard behaviour. However I would like to know how you guys solved this issue.

This is a sample of the code that I'm using:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
var toCsv = require('to-csv');
// obj is a just a standard JavaScript object.
res.send(toCsv(obj));
```

I would like that the person using the API can retrieve data in a CSV format without actually downloading a file

Comment: What is the issue? What would you like to happen? I only see what you don't want.

Comment: Sorry, the data should be returned in a CSV format without forcing the user to download a file. As I think of it now I'm not exactly sure this is standard behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Maybe have a look at this question:
[How does browser determine whether to download or show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096172/how-does-browser-determine-whether-to-download-or-show)

It's your browser that decides that content of the type "*text/csv*" should be downloaded.

You should simply consider using another content-type, if you just want the csv to show in the browser as plain text.

Try this instead:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```